# How to cross join some of rows from table A to some of columns from table B

Tags: mysql

I have two table as table A and table B :

table A

```
+----------+-----------+--------+
| s_number | sname     | city   |
+----------+-----------+--------+
| s1       | fanavaran | tehran |
| s2       | iranghate | tabriz |
| s3       | poladin   | tariz  |
+----------+-----------+--------+
```

table B

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| p_number | color | type   | city   |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| p1       | red   | ahan   | tehran |
| p2       | green | mes    | tabriz |
| p3       | blue  | bereng | shiraz |
| p4       | red   | ahan   | tehran |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I want to cross join table A where city = 'tehran' to color and type columns from table B.

How can I do?

Comment: Your question is very basic you can get it done by yourself if you read SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query...

```
select * from table_a as a INNER JOIN table_b as b ON a.city = b.city where a.city = 'tehran'
```

Answer (score 0):

/*    Try This One below */

```
select A.City,B.Color,B.type from A cross join B where A.City = 'tehran';

OR 

select A.City,B.Color,B.type from A,B where A.City = 'tehran';
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a left join on table A so that all the items from table A are listed even if they do not exist in table B.

```
select A.city, B.color, B.type  from A left join B on A.city=B.city  where A.city="tehran";
```